# Scala all possible combinations

Tags: algorithm, scala, combinations

I'm having hard time doing this task. Let's say I have this data:

```
0| PRECIOUS LETS
1| GANDALF
2| AYYY
```

Now I want to print all combinations - take a single word from every line and make a sentence out of it. It's kind of hard to explain, so I'll give an example solution to this problem above(there are two solutions to this) :

```
1) PRECIOUS GANDALF AYY  //first words from all 3 lines
2) LETS GANDALF AYY      //now another solution is to take 'LETS' instead of 'PRECIOUS' from first line
```

Now it's clear if I added one more word in 1-3 sentence i would have even more possible solutions. I have been struggling for quite some time now with this and any help would be sooo much appreciated!

Thank you soo much!! ^^

Comment: This is called the Cartesian Product; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Most_common_implementation_(set_theory)

Comment: @m69 Oh!! That's cool! Thank you for pointing this out. I will study this ^^

Comment: It's one of the most often asked questions with the algorithm tag, because no one seems to know its name, and that makes it difficult to search. It has its own tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cartesian-product

Comment: "It's one of the most often asked questions with the algorithm tag, because no one seems to know its name" – Really? This is basic high school math, are there really programmers who didn't have basic set theory in school?

Comment: @JörgWMittag loads - esp those w/o maths/comp science degrees

Comment: Currently I'm studying Software Engineering and I would never think that this solution would be a high school problem. Maybe I just suck :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try:

```
// For input in the form of List[List[String]]:
val input: List[List[String]] = List(
  List("PRECIOUS", "LETS"),
  List("GANDALF"),
  List("AYYY")
)

val result: List[List[String]] = input.tail.foldLeft(input.head.map(List(_))) {
  (res, nextList) => res.flatMap(sentence => nextList.map(word => sentence :+ word))
}
```

Note that if any of the input lists is empty, the result would be empty (not sure what your requirement is in that case, can be easily changed to skip empty "lines")

Comment: Wow! Thank youu! ^^

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure there's a slightly simpler (and potentially more efficient) solution hiding somewhere in here, I'm sure someone would post it if I don't...

Comment: I've been struggling with this for too long to care about performance now. Thanks :D

Comment: Not simpler or more efficient, but this would take some strokes off your [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) game: `for {sentence <- _ ; word <- _} yield sentence :+ word`

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know scala, but here is the pseudocode:

```
function solve (int listIndex, String current):
    if (listIndex == lists.size()):
        print(current)
        return
    for int i = 0 to lists[listIndex].size():
        solve(listIndex + 1, current + lists[listIndex][i])

solve(0, "")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely try this out! ^^